# My sort is not being rerendered as I want to sort datas according to the user selection

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, react-router

My sorting is working but sometimes my data doesnot change as I select the option no change occurs , I guess I am not using useEffect correctly So I want what am I doing wrong , I am very confused

```
const { data: property, isFetching, refetch } = useQuery(['PropertySearch', startDate, endDate, where, adultCount, childCount], propertyAvaibility, {
    retry: false,
    enabled: !!data
})

useEffect(() => {
    const sortArray = type => {
        const types = {
            number_of_bars: 'number_of_bars',
            starting_price: 'starting_price',
        };
        const sortProperty = types[type];
        const sorted = property?.sort((a, b) => b[sortProperty] - a[sortProperty]);
        setData(sorted);
    };
    sortArray(sortType);
}, [sortType]);

<select onChange={(e) => setSortType(e.target.value)} className="form-control">
   <option value="number_of_bars">number_of_bars</option>
    <option value="starting_price">starting_price</option>                             
</select>

      {
                                property?.map((item) => (
                                    <PropertyCard
                                        key={item?.id}
                                        title={item?.title}
                                        image={item?.cover_image?.url}
                                        location={item.address}
                                        displayFooter={false}
                                        displayButton={false}
                                        rating={true}
                                        item={item}
                                        type={item?.brand_name}
                                        link="property">
                                        {item?.description?.slice(0, 150)}
                                    </PropertyCard>
                                ))
                        }
```

Comment: I don't see anywhere you define `setData`, could you show that in your code too?

Comment: const [data, setData] = useState([]);

const [sortType, setSortType] = useState('rating');

I have also initalized hook up there but my sorted data is no updating as i want

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is you're using `property?.map` which is always referred to your original list.

For a possible fix, you could modify it to `data?.map` which is your sorted list.

And you also need to set a default value for data

```
const [data, setData] = useState(property); //`property` is from your fetched data
```

Full change can be

```
const { data: property, isFetching, refetch } = useQuery(['PropertySearch', startDate, endDate, where, adultCount, childCount], propertyAvaibility, {
    retry: false,
    enabled: !!data
})

const [data, setData] = useState(property); //set `property` as your default data
const [sortType, setSortType] = useState('rating');

useEffect(() => {
    const sortArray = type => {
        const types = {
            number_of_bars: 'number_of_bars',
            starting_price: 'starting_price',
        };
        const sortProperty = types[type];
        const sorted = property?.sort((a, b) => b[sortProperty] - a[sortProperty]);
        setData(sorted);
    };
    sortArray(sortType);
}, [sortType]);

const displayedData = data?.length ? data : property //check if data is available

<select onChange={(e) => setSortType(e.target.value)} className="form-control">
   <option value="number_of_bars">number_of_bars</option>
    <option value="starting_price">starting_price</option>                             
</select>

      {
                                displayedData?.map((item) => ( //the main change is here
                                    <PropertyCard
                                        key={item?.id}
                                        title={item?.title}
                                        image={item?.cover_image?.url}
                                        location={item.address}
                                        displayFooter={false}
                                        displayButton={false}
                                        rating={true}
                                        item={item}
                                        type={item?.brand_name}
                                        link="property">
                                        {item?.description?.slice(0, 150)}
                                    </PropertyCard>
                                ))
                        }
```

Comment: Thanks Nick Sir , Are you free I want to learn react with you.

Comment: You can find my personal info on my LinkedIn profile. You can reach out to me whenever you have questions :D @BuildThough

Comment: but has my answer solved your problems? @BuildThough

Comment: In your answer data is used before initialization

Comment: I just added this line `const displayedData = data?.length ? data : property` and use `displayedData?.map` instead. Could you check it works or not? @BuildThough

Comment: component is not being rerendered I think we should check useEffect dependencies

Comment: which value is undefined in your case? @BuildThough

Comment: Awesome! Could you mark the answer solved too? That would help people facing a similar problem like yours in the future :D @BuildThough

Comment: I am having a problem in authentication could you please help me sir

Comment: could you tell me briefly about what your authentication problem is? @BuildThough

Comment: I am creating a custom hook as useAuth and a provider as contextProvider and I want to setToken in localStorage whenever login is implemented. I have implemented all the code and I just want to know if it is right approach as I think i have no tdone it in better way

Comment: You should not set user tokens in local storage. The proper way should be that tokens in cookies instead. You can check it out here (https://pragmaticwebsecurity.com/articles/oauthoidc/localstorage-xss.html) @BuildThough

Comment: I know that sir , but my project has told me to put in lcoalstorage.

Comment: Could you try to simulate your code somewhere? That would help in understanding your question though @BuildThough

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71724578/need-help-for-authentication-in-react-js-i-am-creating-a-custom-hook-called-us